# Automate ssh from mac to iPhone

Tags: ios, macos, ssh

I am working on a tool for iOS, it's based on shell scripts that push various stuff to the device and then performs various operations based on what's pushed on the device.

In this case the device is going to be a jailbroken iPhone. And I would like to connect to it from mac.. so, I have used "usbmux" to ssh over usb and it works great. (cheers :D)

Now, the problem is, i would like to completely automate the ssh-ing process, assuming the password is the default 'alpine'. To avoid user interaction.

This is what i have tried and it doesn't give me the expected outcome.

```
expect <<< 'spawn ssh root@localhost -p 2222; expect "*?password:*"; send "alpine\r";'
```

I read about ssh-keygen and few other options but they seem to require initial manual interactions. Please help me completely automate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution ..
Execute the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh -q user@hostname
expect "assword"
send "alpine\r"
interact
```

Works like a charm!! :)